# Classic ASP Prepared Statement SELECT Not Working

Tags: asp-classic, ado, adodb

I have been trying to move all queries to use prepared statements. I have been able to get INSERT and UPDATE commands to work fine, but for some reason SELECT statements are not working. Using a standard query, i am able to obtain a row using the following.

```
strSQL = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = " & request.querystring("id")
Set rs = objConnection.Execute(strSQL, ,adCmdText)
```

When i convert this into a prepared statement, it appears to return a result, but nothing is there .

```
set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = objConnection
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = ?"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText 
cmd.Prepared = true
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@id", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, request.querystring("id")))
rs = cmd.Execute()
```

The query returns no data, but for some reason, the following If statement passes as if there was some data. The first query will output the username when this line runs. When the prepared statement runs, it outputs nothing, but the if statement passes as if were true. It doesnt appear to be throwing any errors.

```
if not (rs.eof and rs.bof) Then Response.Write(rs("username"))
```

Comment: Do you have `On Error Resume Next` somewhere in the code?

Comment: `Set rs = cmd.Execute()`  ?

Comment: Good catch @TimWilliams, missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from @TimWilliams was one of the issues, there was also a second issue. ID was an integer field and the prepared statement was sending it as a varchar. seems crazy that there are datatypes but the following combined with the comment from Tim resolved the issue.

```
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@id", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, request.querystring("id")))
```

Changes to

```
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@id", 3, 1, , request.querystring("id")))
```